# How to decrypt a cakephp 3 cookie

Tags: php, cookies, cakephp-3.0

Assume that you have a cookie string like this:

```
Q2FrZQ==.AAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

How can you decrypt this in cakephp 3 by using AES ?

It seems like `Cake\Utility\Security::decrypt($cipher, $key, $hmacSalt = null)` does it:

[http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/security.html#Cake\Utility\Security::decrypt](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/security.html#Cake%5CUtility%5CSecurity::decrypt)

But what about the parameters ? `hmacSalt` is application's salt value, but what's the `key` value in second argument ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I store encrypted cookies in database. And sometimes I need to decrypt them for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at the source of the cookie component, the `$hmacSalt` argument is not being used,

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L437](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L437)**

and the `$key` argument  is fed with the components `key` config option value, which holds

> Encryption key used when encrypted cookies are enabled. Defaults to Security.salt.

- **[https://github.com/cakephp/.../Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L55](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L55)**
- **[https://github.com/cakephp/.../Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L125](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L125)**

So unless you have manually configured the cookie components `key` option, all you'd need for decrypting an AES encrypted cookie value, should be

```
Security::decrypt($value, Security::salt());
```

where `$value` is the properly extracted and decoded, raw encrypted data as the cookie component would pass it:

```
$prefix = 'Q2FrZQ==.';
$value = base64_decode(substr($value, strlen($prefix)));
```

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L431-L432](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php#L431-L432)**